# Where is the sourcecode for http.server python3.5?

Tags: python, github

Where is the sourcecode for http.server python3.5? Is there a git repository for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a copy on your hard drive:

```
>>> import http.server
>>> http.server
 <module 'http.server' from '/pathTo/your/python/installation/http/server.py'>
```

This assumes you have Python 3.5 installed and run it.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) has a reference to the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/http/server.py).

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't use Git, they use Mercurial--partly because Mercurial is written in Python.

It's here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/http/server.py

---

**Update**: Since this was originally answered, Python has switched to using Git and GitHub.  The code is now here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/http/server.py

Comment: Not anymore, CPythno has shifter to GitHub. Most recent is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py